Editing villager data via commands sytax?
I was wondering what the difference between these two methods of editing villagers data via commands was. Both work, but I was wondering if one is better. I have the following commands:
execute as @e[type=villager,tag=!cookie,nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:farmer"},Offers:{Recipes:[{sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie"}}]}}] run data modify entity @s Offers{}.Recipes[{sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie"}}].buy{id:"minecraft:emerald"}.Count set value 1
execute as @e[type=villager,tag=!cookie,nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:farmer"},Offers:{Recipes:[{sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie"}}]}}] run data modify entity @s Offers{}.Recipes[].sell{id:"minecraft:cookie"}.Count set value 6
execute as @e[type=villager,tag=!cookie,nbt={VillagerData:{profession:"minecraft:farmer"},Offers:{Recipes:[{sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie"}}]}}] run data modify entity @s Offers.Recipes[{sell:{id:"minecraft:cookie"}}].maxUses set value 6

I would assume that the first one is first finding a recipe where the villager is selling cookies, then changing the .count of that trade where the .buy is emeralds.
The second is searching all recipes and changing any where the .sell is cookie
Similar for the third finding any trade that sells cookies and changes its max uses.
Again, is there a "best way" to minimize conflict?

Which way has less lag and glitchiness? Also which one is easier for you to change the contents of the sell.buy of a villager?

Which ever answer you give is the one for you. Now, some people might have a better answer to give, I just thought that might be a good way to help you figure it out.

My mistake, I forgot to at you.

Best way is to use absolute references; I'll write up a full answer tomorrow (in 12 hours). But basically, you can reference UUIDs to @e the villager and the villager trade list can be accessed as an array...

There are multiple ways to Rome; to reference and edit the same set of data. You can drill down to individual values or replace a hunk (whole object) at once... You do you that is the most convenient way.
With /data modify you can access entities more granularly now.
First of all, if you haven't already... You can directly reference specific entities with their UUIDs.
If you: /say @e, you'll get a list of entities, something like this:

For more information, see this wiki page.
Furthermore, if you need to target a bunch of entities arbitarily, you can always just tag an entity (/tag command).
/tag <targets> add <tag_name>

And reference them with @e[tag=<tag_name>].
So now your command looks something like this:
/data modify entity {uuid} ...

As you know, villager offers can be found in the tree structure under Offers.Recipes, and it is an array...

Being that Offers.Recipies is an array, you can access members of an array with [] square bracket notation.
For example, if I wanted to edit the first slot of a villager, I would:
(Any one of these sets of commands will do the same thing)
data modify entity {uuid} Offers.Recipes[0] set value { "maxUses": 24, "buy": { "id": "minecraft:emerald", "count": 1 }, "sell": { "count": 64, "id": "minecraft:diamond" }}

data modify entity {uuid} Offers.Recipes[0].maxUses set value 24
data modify entity {uuid} Offers.Recipes[0].sell.count set value 64
data modify entity {uuid} Offers.Recipes[0].sell.id set value "minecraft:diamond"
data modify entity {uuid} Offers.Recipes[0].buy.count set value 1

See this wiki page for more information on /data.

I wish to have a command that can be used on any villager, not hardcoded to a specific UUID, as can be seen in my initial commands. I also wish to edit, not overwrite, so multiple commands seem to be the way to go.

You can replace {uuid} with a selector as well, I was using that as an example - But the point is that you can bulk edit a value if you select a non-leaf node and just use JSON notation. There isn't a right answer about which one to use.
The best practice is either to predict the index ahead of time, or to append your offer
